# How to use TSQL FOR XML to generate one element per row

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

Given the following query:

```
select name from student
```

I want to generate the following XML:

```
<students>
    <name>Alice</name>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <name>Charles</name>
</students>
```

I ***do not*** want to generate the following XML. The code consuming the generated XML won't accept anything but the format shown above.

```
<students>
    <row><name>Alice</name></row>
    <row><name>Bob</name></row>
    <row><name>Charles</name></row>
</students>
```

Can this be done with TSL's [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) clause?

Text replacement on the resulting XML doesn't count. I can do that already. I already know [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), too.

Comment: yes, select name from student for xml path(''), root('students')

Comment: @siggemannen Bingo. I could've sworn I tried that. I must be losing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to do this, depending on how you would want other columns to show up.

Either use no `PATH`, which would keep other columns using their own node names, but no parent node.

```sql
SELECT
  s.name
FROM student s
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('students'), TYPE;
```

Or an unnamed column, where other unnamed colums would be squashed together into a single text value inside `<name>`

```sql
SELECT
  s.name + ''
FROM student s
FOR XML PATH('name'), ROOT('students'), TYPE;
```